# Tabbed page swipes gets in the way of a horizontal scroll Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I want to know how to disable the swipe in a tabbed page. As I have a sort of horizontal scroll listview on a page the swipe keeps changing the page instead of scrolling the listview.

This is how I got the tabbed page to work.

App.xaml.cs

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace App1
{
 public partial class App : Application
 {
          public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        SetMainPage();

    }
    public static void SetMainPage()
    {
                Current.MainPage = new TabbedPage
        {
        Children =
            {
                new NavigationPage(new page1())
                {
                    Title = "page1",
                    Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_feed.png",null,null)
                },
                new NavigationPage(new page2())
                {
                    Title = "page2",
                    Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_feed.png",null,null)
                },
                new NavigationPage(new page3())
                {
                    Title = "page3",
                    Icon = Device.OnPlatform<string>("tab_feed.png",null,null)
                },
            }
        };
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SetIsSwipePagingEnabled.

```
var page = new TabbedPage
{
    Children =
    {
        new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
        {
            Title = "page1"
        },
        new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
        {
            Title = "page2"
        },
        new NavigationPage(new MainPage())
        {
            Title = "page3"
        }
    }
};


Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.TabbedPage.SetIsSwipePagingEnabled(page, false);
Current.MainPage = page;
```

Comment: Thanks! That was solution! I'm completely new to Xamarin so, thanks for letting me know!